# I miss home and I like cornbread

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

As yesterday's puzzle has yet to be solved, I tried to make this one a tiny bit easier.

> I'm one star of many, yet we're all bound together,
> Hot, dry, humid most days, It depends on the weather.
>
> I'm friends with the man whose kicks cause a large bang,
> Pardon the way I'm speaking, It's not really slang.
>
> Perhaps I can fancy you with a pie,
> Or maybe some chili as we say goodbye.
>
> Now, just what on earth am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> TEXAS

I'm one star of many, yet we're all bound together,

> One star on the flag of 50

Hot, dry, humid most days, It depends on the weather.

> Apt description of Texas weather

I'm friends with the man whose kicks cause a large bang,

> Chuck Norris!

Pardon the way I'm speaking, It's not really slang.

> Texas Drawl

Perhaps I can fancy you with a pie,
Or maybe some chili as we say goodbye.

> Stereotypical Texas Food

Now, just what on earth am I?

Comment: That's correct. Good job! I'm from Texas, so I wasn't sure if people would understand all of the references.

Comment: I'm from Toronto and understood.  So your clues were pretty coherent.

Comment: "I'm one star of many" Are you *lone*ly?